# Copy files under an HDFS location

Tags: hdfs

I am wondering if someone could answer my below queries regarding HDFS permission issue

```
l1491**@0a2a450d ~ $ hdfs dfs -ls /ds/egress/meta
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hive hdfs          0 2020-12-16 09:38 /ds/egress/meta/A00A03
l1491**@0a2a450d ~ $ hdfs dfs -put test /ds/egress/meta/A00A03
l1491**@0a2a450d ~ $ hdfs dfs -ls /ds/egress/meta/A00A03
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 l1491** hdfs          0 2020-12-16 09:58 /ds/egress/meta/A00A03/test
```

My user is l1491**, and on /ds/egress/meta/A00A03 path the users:group access is hive:hdfs, My user is not the part of any group named Hive, or HDFS either but I can copy my local file test to that HDFS directory. I am not sure why I should be able to copy a file with my user on that directory which has HIVE:HDFS permsion not anythingr elated to my user?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you set `dfs.permissions.enabled` to `false` so HDFS doesn't perform permission checking

Comment: Actually, it is true!,l***@0a2a450d ~/src $ hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.permissions.enabled
true

Comment: @Mah hmmm, maybe the user is a superuser(a user who start HDFS processes for example) or is in the supergroup.